# Want to include a file from different files, that include a file

Tags: php, relative-path

The title maybe sounds a little weird, but let's say I have file A, and B. A and B have both

```
include_once("includes/includes.php");
```

And in Includes.php there's this line:

```
include_once("admin/plugins/list.php");
```

Which works fine on files that are on the same level as admin (folder).
But B, already is in the folder Admin, and has the following code:

```
include_once("../includes/includes.php");
```

And that works, only I got errors when opening a file that's in the admin folder, because it can't find the folder admin, in the folder admin. And I know I can remove the admin using some if statements, but I have more folder with this problem.

And yes, I already tried using **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']**, and "/" but that doesn't work.

Comment: Build paths relative to the folder the parent script is in: `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../includes/includes.php';`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define a constant like
`define('SV_ROOT', 'path/to/yourroot');`

And then make all includes relative to it.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that is always the same as it comes to includes is the document root. So I'd say print your docroot to screen en see what you get.

Just to be sure, you are not requesting it to late (like requesting after you requested the function you need) and you are not requesting it double.

To be sure, can you post the error, the doc root output and the path where it should be according to you.

Comment: The error is:      Warning: include_once(/usr/local/apache/htdocs/admin/plugins/plugins.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /home/a2017505/public_html/includes/includes.php on line 51

Comment: *With $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], but I need a piece of code that'll work on more servers, because I'm building a CMS